# Is it possible to rename a Windows 10 device when using Autopilot to join it to the domain and Intune management?

Tags: windows-10, entra-id, microsoft-intune

Realizing that naming a PC is old school, I would still like to know if it is possible to rename a Windows 10 device either as part of the AutoPilot process or later through Intune.

Another acceptable answer would be answering how to deal with randomly named machines in Azure AD, when machine names are left alone.

Comment: This is now a built-in feature of Intune.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because both the question, and the answers from the same era, are no longer relevant due to new features in Intune that make it very easy to set/change a computers name.

Comment: I think the question is still relevant, now that's the feature is built into intune you can answer your own question by showing how to rename a device with this feature.

Comment: I meant to vote for deletion, so someone could start fresh. If I can find a moment, I'll try to rewrite the Q&A. Otherwise, it would be less confusing for everyone if this question was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rename a Windows 10 device, you could create a device configuration profile with the custom OMA-URI setting. The steps are in the following:

1. Open the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) and navigate to **Intune** > **Device configuration** > **Profiles**;
2. On the **Devices configuration – Profiles** blade, click **Create profile** to open the **Create profile** blade;
3. On the **Create profile** blade, provide the following information and click **Create**;

   - **Name**: Provide a valid name;
   - **Description**: (Optional) Provide a description;
   - **Platform**: Select Windows 10 and later;
   - **Profile type**: Select Custom;
   - **Settings**: See **Step 4**.
4. On the **Custom OMA-URI Settings** blade, provide the following information and click **Add** to open the **Add** **row** blade. On the **Add row** blade, provide the following information and click **OK** (and click **OK** in the **Custom OMA-URI** blade);

   - **Name**: Provide a valid name;
   - **Description**: (Optional) Provide a description;
   - **OMA-URI**: ./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Accounts/Domain/ComputerName;
   - **Data type**: Select String;
   - **Value**: CLDCLN%SERIAL% (or use the other example of CLDCLN%RAND:6%).

Note: At some point in time this configuration will probably become available in the Azure portal without the requirement of creating a custom OMA-URI.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Your answer pointed me toward the CSP documentation ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/accounts-csp ) and a nice (and VERY similar) blog post ( https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/rename-a-device-via-windows-10-mdm/ ) on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Autopilot profile has an option to apply a computer name template, however the documentation mentions that it requires the latest Windows Insider.

If you can, I would try to check if it works with W10 1809 build.

Check OOBE settings here: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/enrollment-autopilot#create-an-autopilot-deployment-profile

AzureAD doens't name the devices, most of the time it uses whatever the device has setup. I'm just not sure in regards to Android, probably it's Intune that names the device as it's always the same "*Android*"